# Queries related to AppExchange Destination org for 2GP

Tags: apex, visualforce, appexchange, 2gp, second-generation-packaging

Please guide me for below queries for a 2GP created :

Created a 2nd Generation package. Steps followed are as below :

1. Source Org - Partner Developer Edition , Namespace created and linked to partner Dev hub org, created package and promoted, using CLI commands(Github as source of truth)
2. Destination org - Created another Partner developer edition org >>> was able to install the package

I have below two queries where I am confused and stuck :

1. In the publishing tab, When I choose Salesforce package solution >> Connect an org >> its not showing anything in solutions Tab.  Which org should we connect - is it destination org(where package is installed) OR source org OR Devhub Org(PBO in this case)?
2. For Security scan portal using checkmarx, which org should we link ? When I link destination org, I am getting error after authentication.

https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/

[image]

Comment: Pls guide me and share any documents/links to refer..I'm stuck here and unable to proceed

Answer (score 0):

In the publishing tab, When I choose Salesforce package solution >> Connect an org >> its not showing anything in solutions Tab.

Solution - We should add org in which we created namespace.

Missing piece was I didn't create Connected App.
After adding connected app, it will reflect in solutions tab.
I followed this blog, which helped me in resolving this issues.

https://salesforce-walker.blogspot.com/2022/01/how-to-add-connected-app-to-second.html

The solution to second query I posted, I will share when I find the same :-)